# Yammer Message API image issue - thumbnail not showing

Tags: facebook-opengraph, yammer

I was able to successfully post to Message API (api/v1/messages.json) without any bug. But now image of the post is not appearing on Yammer's activity stream. even though I'm sure it receives it, because when I'm trying to share the same post from Yammer it shows the thumbnail.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Thanks.

```
  'body': 'some text from textarea',
  'og_url': window.location.href,
  'og_image': model.get('thumbnailUrl'),
  'og_title': model.get('title'),
  'og_description': model.get('description')
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I see that when I click into the post it shows the correct image, but on the stream it shows our app logo :(

Answer (score 0):

If you set the recent activity post with a different og_url than what is shared on the yammer wall, then the problem will be solved.

For instance, share to the wall with https://recognizeapp.com/... and to the recent activity as https://www.recognizeapp.com/...